# How to know the "remote" in git pre-push hook file

Tags: git, githooks

In the "pre-push" file, I can get some params using "
`read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha`", but I wanna do some restrictions stuff according to the specific remote repo(yes, there's mutiple remote address in my project)， so how can I do this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remote name and url are supplied as parameters to the pre-push.

`remote="$1
 url="$2"`

will give the information you needed