# git multi remote repositories with almost same files

Tags: git

I have files  `a1`, `a2`, ..., `b`, `c` and remote repositories `github`, `gitlab`. `github` track `a*` and `b`, while `gitlab` track `a*` and `c`

Now I want to update `a1`, how can I deal with it?

The ugliest way is to clone the two repositories into two folders, update `a1` in one folder, commit and push, copy `a1` to the other folder, commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

- add the second remote to your "base" repository,
- push to remote A then remote B

For example, if your repository is "linked" to github :

- add `gitlab` as a new remote :

  ```
  git remote add gitlab <url to gitlab repo>

  # if you wanted to give "mysuperduperrepo" as a local name, you would write :
  git remote add mysuperduperrepo <url to gitlab repo>
  ```
- push `b` to github :

  ```
  git push origin b
  ```
- push `c` to gitlab :

  ```
  git push gitlab c

  # if you have chosen to name your remote "mysuperduperrepo" :
  git push mysuperduperrepo c
  ```

---

If, additionally, you want to prevent `c` to be pushed to `github` and `b` to be pushed to `gitlab`, you can do so, on your local repo, by using a `pre-push` hook.

See [the docs for git hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push), and for example [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837679/how-to-know-the-remote-in-git-pre-push-hook-file) to see how you can check "am I pushing to gitlab or git

Comment: So how I commit and push after I change `a1`?

Comment: `git push origin a1`, `git push gitlab a1`